# Using a C++ library (boost) with inline-c-cpp

Tags: c++, haskell, boost, ffi

In Haskell, I would like to call a function from the [boost C++ library](http://www.boost.org/) with the help of [inline-c-cpp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-c-cpp).

After downloading the `boost` library, how should I configure the `cabal` file and the fields `extra-lib-dirs` and `extra-include-dirs` in `stack.yaml` ?

In the `cabal` file, I write: `extra-libraries: boost`, and I have tried several folders in `extra-lib-dirs` and `extra-include-dirs`, but I always get `Missing C library: boost`.

### Edit

This is my attempt after @n.m.'s comments. In `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-include-dirs:
- U:\Data\C\boost_1_64_0
```

In the cabal file:

```
  extra-libraries:     stdc++
  c-sources:           src/Main.cpp
```

My module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Main
  where
import qualified Language.C.Inline.Cpp as C

C.context C.cppCtx

C.include "<iostream>"
C.include "<boost/math/special_functions/owens_t.hpp>"

main :: C.CDouble -> C.CDouble -> IO ()
main h a = do
  [C.block| void {
      std::cout << "Hello, Owen! " << boost::math::owens_t($(double h), $(double a)) << std::endl;
    } |]
```

The code compiles without issue. However, when I run `main 1 1` in `GHCi`, I get the error

```
ghc.exe: C:\HaskellProjects\inlinecpp\.stack-work\install\e77882c1\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.0.2\inlinecpp-0.1.0.0-IWaed3tDnUhE52nToDO1Sq\HSinlinecpp-0.1.0.0-IWaed3tDnUhE52nToDO1Sq.o: unknown symbol `_Unwind_Resume'
```

### Edit

This works if I do and run an executable file. But I'd like to use it in GHCi.

Comment: Boost is a collection of libraries. It is normally split between several dozens library files. It is unlikely that your system has a single library named boost. Telling which functions you want to call could help.

Comment: @n.m. Ok, thank you. I want to call `owens_t` in `boost/math/special_functions`.

Comment: owens_t is a template-only function and is not in any linkable library.

Comment: That means it's not possible ? Sad, I can call it from `R`.

Comment: No, this means you don't have any library to link against. You only need to specify `extra-include-dirs`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm going to try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147574/discussion-between-n-m-and-stephane-laurent).

Comment: @n.m. This works with ghc 8.2.1 !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code posted in the **Edit** works in GHCi with `ghc 8.2.1`.

```
Prelude Main> main 0.5 0.5
Hello, Owen! 0.0644886
```